# Mail Script Help

Tags: mail.app, applescript, evernote

I forward a lot of emails to Evernote and Nozbe (similar to OmniFocus) as I work to get my inbox to zero.  When I am on my iPhone, I move emails to folders (Evernote, Nozbe, or Archives) depending on how I want to process them.

When I get back to the office, I forward those emails one at a time.  There has to be a way to automate this so that when my Mac discovers, for example, that there is an email in the Evernote folder, it just forwards it to my unique Evernote email address.

I am a novice at scripting and I don't know how to make this work.  I tried using Apple Mail rules, but I don't see where I can identify emails based upon the folder they are in. Automator doesn't have a service for forwarding emails in Apple Mail (though I see they have one for Outlook).

Any ideas? I'd toast a cold one in honor of someone who would help a brother out. ;-)

Comment: Ideally - would you like the mail processing to happen on the server or on the Mac. If on the Mac, should it be continuous, or something you kick off when you wish to process things?

Comment: Mail.app has great automatic forwarding feature in the Rules. Check it out.

Comment: bmike - actually, you may be on to something.  I actually think it may be more elegant to have a gmail script.  I tried that before, but I messed it up so bad that I forgot to even mention it.  If I were smart enough to write a gmail script to forward a specific label to an email address, I think it'd work best.  Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

So bmike got me rethinking my question, and I found a slightly different solution to the problem: [Automatically forward "Starred in Gmail" messages to OmniFocus](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88221/automatically-forward-starred-in-gmail-messages-to-omnifocus?rq=1)

In this case, I just set a gmail script that, when I flag an email (or "star" on gmail), it forwards the email to a specific address, and then unflags the email.  Not exactly what I set out to do, but a solution nonetheless.

The only caveat is that my labels idea would be able to forward emails to different special email accounts (you could have one for omnifocus, one for Evernote, etc.), but if I'm going to be picky, I should learn to code, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Gmail anyway than there is another option that might work for you.  [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/gmail) has a Gmail channel, which will allow you to forward that email to another address whenever a specific label is added. This should be a good option for what you are trying to do.